# Getting categories of posts under a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT with the following taxonomies: category, taxonomy_1 and taxonomy_2 (the last two are non-hierarchical).

I want to get programmatically all the terms of the "category" taxonomy but only of the posts with a given meta value — that meta value is storing the ID of another taxonomy (`taxonomy_2`).

So it would be: Categories -> Posts -> Specific meta value

I've tried the following without success:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'       => 'taxonomy_key_in_CPT',
        'value'     => 'value_of_taxonomy_key_in_CPT',
        'compare'   => "=",
    )
)

$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

But this will still return all the categories under the CPT. Am I doing something funny?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPSE.  I believe you are looking for the `get_terms()` function.  This will return all of the terms for a particular taxonomy, and not the posts.

Pass your taxonomy slug in the array of arguments and set the `hide_empty` to false so you get a complete list, like this:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_1',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Full documentation can be found code reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: Thank you @jdm2112. I'm actually trying to get the `category` taxonomy only used in posts using another taxonomy. Am I making sense hehe? I think I need to update my question.

Comment: I updated my question. And I think that were I got confused is that the `meta_query` is looking for meta values for the `category` taxonomy right? Not on the posts... lol